# Can i create a table like structure in redis like "ID , KEY , DATA , STATUS , EMAIL"

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

i'm very new to redis. we have a requirement where I need to create a table like structure in redis.

ID | Name | Region | Time
01 | Aaa  | s1     | ...
02 | Bbb  | s2     | ...

1. I need to add constraint for Primary Key(ID,Name,Region)

Comment: You probably want a hash https://redis.io/topics/data-types where the key in redis is the primary key you need (you may have to calculate this out side of redis since you want it based on a combination of values)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Hash map storing all the row of the table and key name should be **Primary Key**. For example

```
// key should be the primary key
hmset user:1:Aaa:s1 id 1 name Aaa Region s1 Time 12:00
hmset user:2:Bbb:s2 id 2 name Bbb Region s2 Time 11:00
```

Key name is the primary Key **user:1:Aaa:s1**. 
If you want to retrieve the key with the different name you have to create key and point to this hash.

For example:

```
// If you want to retrieve with the userId.
set user:1 user:1:Aaa:s1
set user:2 user:2:Bbb:s2
```

Comment: is there a way to retrieve data by name?

Comment: Yes there is, as the name is repetitive you have to make the set like **user:Aaa** which contains the hashIds **user:1:Aaa:s1**. The commands is ```sadd user:Aaa:user:1:Aaa:s1```